# js xhr.response store in localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, get, xmlhttprequest, local-storage

Is it possible to store **xhr.response** in local-storage ,  **code :** `var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();xhr.open('GET', 'http://cdn.dmsapp.tk/'+appUrl+'/'+evt+'?authToken='+this.getuserservice.authorizationfun()+'&force=false');localStorage['tifPdfFileObj'] = JSON.stringify(xhr.response);xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';xhr.onload = function (e) { localStorage['tifPdfFileObj'] = JSON.stringify(xhr.response);}`
 I need to store the **xhr.response object in local-storage** or some where, to use it whenever i want instead of hit api for same image.when i try to stringify the response, it returns empty(**{}**).How to store in local storage and use it.
**current usage :** `var buffer = xhr.response;var tiff = new Tiff({buffer: buffer});`

Comment: no need to stringify. localStorage takes everything